# How to create image from docker containing that includes volume data?

Tags: docker

Consider a Dockerfile that declares two volumes

```
FROM someimage
# ...
VOLUME ["/foo", "/bar"]
```

and a container started from that image, that does a bind mount for one of those volumes:

```
docker run --name mycontainer -d -v /some/path:/foo myimage
```

If I created a new image from that container using

```
docker commit mycontainer myexportedimage
```

both paths, `/foo` and `/bar`, will be excluded in the exported image.

How do I create a runnable (i.e. maintaining meta data from Dockerfile) image from `mycontainer` that includes the data from both paths, `/foo` (bind mounted) and `/bar` (volume as declared by Dockerfile), so if I exported the image to another Docker host, all data would be present?

Comment: That's the point of volumes. Don't put that in a volume if you want data to be on the image rather than on the volume. I recommend you to read some docker documentation.

Comment: @FlorinAsăvoaie I know, but that's just the situation I have and need to handle

Comment: No, it is not. It is a situation where you need to understand how containers work and what is the difference between a volume and an image, and what the Linux "mount" command does.

Comment: @FlorinAsăvoaie I was given the job to "rescue" containers from a server I have neither setup nor maintained until now, and now am looking for a possibility to somehow get along with the situation. I know the differences and what *mount* does. That's why I'm looking for a way (a script, a tool, ...) to somehow handle those containers and do my job.

Comment: If you need to move volumes, inspect the container to get the volume target, and move that. Also, don't declare volumes inside of a Dockerfile, that feature exists for historical reasons and only causes issues in current environments.

Answer (score 1):

Disclaimer : answer is incomplete because you won't be able to manage that from a Dockerfile like asked and the point is taken that "we should not be in this situation and we should not try to solve this problem in that manner".

I know this is an old question but I ran into the same situation and here's what I did.

You can create an image with the content of your volumes using `docker cp` to import the content of your volume locally into the container (just copy it somewhere else in your running container and be aware that this duplicates data so watch you filesystem usage). Or `exec` into it and use `cp` commands to copy the data in your mounted volume somewhere else (ie: in a `tmp` directory).

Then, you can `docker commit` that container to turn it into an image.
Run a new container from that new image without using docker volumes and move back the files copied where they should be if the volumes where mounted.

Now, use `docker commit` again to get a reusable image from the container where you copied your volumes contents.

You can now tag and/or push that image to a registry or `docker save` it into an archive and use it where you need it.

Comment: Would you give some example commands of how to do the copy and relink parts please?